# How to make item path have no spaces between words?

Tags: sxa

I created template inherited from redirect, when i create item from this template i found that item name in item path have white space not "-" as items created from template inherited from page.
any idea how to make item path correct and have no spaces between word without inherited from page??

Comment: I am not sure if SXA has space to dash built in, but I always use this https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/seo-friendly-urls-in-sitecore-prevention-is-better-than-cure/. Its better than renaming in the link provider.

Comment: SXA used to handle a name change upon item creation. New versions will stop doing that as now it can be configured in Sitecore.

Answer (score 1):

in the sitecore config file there is a section: `<encodeNameReplacements>`
you can add a line like this:

```
<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-"/>
```

That is how we have done it, and it works well